# Business Intelligence for VS2013 - Unable to connect to report server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue right here, after installing Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 from  : [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42313) and restarting my machine, I did encounter these issues :

1) Main problem I am not able to connect to my Reporting services configuration manager, this is my error :
 [image]
    Also connecting to `http://myMachineName/Reports` will not show up any page whatsoever.
    From what I've found on msdn, a process called SQL Services Reports should be running, I have no such kind of a process, here's an ordered by alphabet list of my processes : 
    [image]

2) Creating a project in VS2013 Ultimate -Report Server Project, after choosing my tables,queries,datasets,etc and preview my report I get this [command prompt](http://prntscr.com/4fy7qr), closing it will result into this [error](http://prntscr.com/4fy835).

I am using 
Win8.1 x64, 
SQL Server 2014, 
Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know SQL EXPRESS doesnt come with Reporting services, neither can I see `SQL Server Reporting Services` installed in your services section. There should be a service running in your services window

[image]

Also I think you need atleast `SQL SERVER EXPRESS WITH ADVANCED SERVICES` to get `SSRS`.

Comment: One question, I also need SQL to connect to connect with my local application to my localhost database. Last time I did install Express with tools, what version should I choose in order to do both those things ?

Comment: nevermind, advanced services includes everything. i will come back with an answer asap.

Comment: I am getting this issue, I am not able to connect from browser 
http://prntscr.com/4fyo77

Comment: It's working with machinename:80/Reports, but I get a blank page,any idea why ?